# Google Maps Boundaries (limiting location data to a Lat/Long Boundary)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, mapkit

Anyone know how to get thew Google Maps API HTTP request/response to only return me Locations that fall within Australia ?

I thought I could just add:

```
bounds=lat, long | lat Long
```

Creating a square boundary based off Coordinates, but Google for some strange reason isn't liking it.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@+Australia&bounds=-9.102097,104.765625|-44.902578,159.697266&sensor=false&region=au", kGoogleGeocodeURL, params];
```

Comment: Is Google returning an error?  Log the entire url string that's being generated and sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, it turns out that the search string was correct, but I needed to use UTF8Encoding, as NSString didn't like the Commas.